# Populate table fields on query execution

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to build an ASP site that populates a Table based on the results of a selection in a ListBox. In order to do this, I've created a GridView table inside a div element.  Currently the default behavior is to show all the items in the specified table in sortable order.

However, I'd like to refine this further to allow for display of matches based on the results from the ListBox selection, but am not sure how to execute this.  The ListBox fires off a `OnSelectionChanged` event to the method defined below and the GridView element is defined as

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataListings"  runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" 
                    OnDataBinding="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int itemSelected = selectTopics.SelectedIndex;
        string[] listing = null;

        switch (itemSelected)//assign listing the array of course numbers
        {
            case 0: 
                break;
            case 1: 
                listing = arts;
                break;

            case 2:
                listing = currentEvents;
                break;

           .... More cases here

            default:
                listing = arts;
                break;


        }
        using (OLLIDBDataContext odb = new OLLIDBDataContext())
        {

            var q = 
                from c in odb.tbl_CoursesAndWorkshops 
                where listing.Contains(c.tbl_Course_Description.tbl_CoursesAndWorkshops.course_workshop_number) 
                select c;

            dataListings.DataSource = q;
            dataListings.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

However, this method never gets fired.  I can see a request being made when changing the selection, but setting a breakpoint at the method declaration does nothing at all.

Based on this, setup, I have three related questions

1. What do I need to modify to get the `OnSelectionChanged` event handler to fire?
2. How can I alter the GridView area to be empty on page load?
3. How do I send the results from the `dataListings.DataBind()` execution to show in the GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer for 1

Set AutoPostBack to true for ListBox1, like

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True".... ></asp:ListBox>
```

### Answer for 2

On selection changes, firstly you need to clear data from GridView, like

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dataListings.DataSource = null;
  dataListings.DataSourceID = null;
  dataListings.DataBind();
  ........... // Other code goes here
}
```

### Answer for 3

Get off OnDataBinding event from GridView

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dataListings"  runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" >
```

Add an event(onselectedindexchanged) to ListBox1, so it looks like

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
 onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
```

Now, in the event ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged, if you have new data in the query to bind GridView then it'll bind the GridView, but below change will have good output.

```
var q = ...; //Your query for getting data goes here.

dataListings.DataSource = q;
dataListings.DataSourceID = null;
dataListings.DataBind();
```

Now, each time GridView will populate with new data from your query.

Answer (score 1):

For part one of your question, add AutoPostBack to the listbox:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"...
```

For part two (to clear a GridView).  You also might want to create an EmptyDataTemplate so you see *something*.

```
    GridView1.DataSource = null;
    GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

And you may have this 'backwards':

`OnDataBinding="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">`

When the ListBox selection changes, assign the datasource to the gridview and call DataBind on the gridview.